# binary data allows external storage - error: Compilation failed for data model at path

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xcode5

Xcode Data model, when i try set option `allows external storage` type `binary data` i have error `error: Compilation failed for data model at path...`. If i not set this option compilation is ok. I use mogenerator, simulator

Comment: You have an attribute on a Core Data entity that you wish to store as Binary Data type with external storage; but the model fails to compile.  Can you tell us more about the entity and the attribute you're working with?  This error may also be encountered when there are .xcdatamodel files in the .xcdatamodeld package that aren't displayed in Xcode.

Comment: Not enough information. What's the full error (including the part you replaced with "...")? Also, please give full details on this attribute and on the entity it belongs to.

Comment: @NSBum Please do as your answer, I will use it as "solved", as indeed I have found  .xcdatamodel file  that was not in the package and it solved the my problem simply by removing him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an attribute on a Core Data entity that you wish to store as Binary Data type with external storage; but the model fails to compile. Can you tell us more about the entity and the attribute you're working with? This error may also be encountered when there are .xcdatamodel files in the .xcdatamodeld package that aren't displayed in Xcode.